# Spring external library beans initialization order

Tags: java, spring

I've encountered a problem in my application and somehow i need to force one bean A to be initialized before another bean B. These beans are provided by external dependencies (different dependencies) so I cannot simply do it with `@DependsOn` annotation.
Is there any solution available?

Comment: "external dependencies" - *is it* a problem? >"While using `@DependsOn`, we must use component-scanning" (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-depends-on#key-points)

Comment: What would be possible implementation then?